# What are various approaches of proving that a permutation group is a subgroup of another?

Tags: finite-groups

I have two permutation groups $G_1=\langle g_1,g_2\rangle$ and $G_2=\langle h_1,h_2\rangle$ acting on $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ respectively. I want to prove that $G_1 \leq G_2$. What are more nontrivial methods to do so?

Comment: The most obvious way is to show $g_1,g_2 \in G_2$.  (Does this count as "trivial"?)

Comment: OK, but how we can show that $g_1,g_2 \in G_2$? We should give a mapping from $\Gamma_1$ to $\Gamma_2$. But what if it's not possible? One can do the same for vector spaces over $\Gamma_i s$

Comment: @Kaave: Are you thinking of $\Gamma$'s as vector spaces or just some sets?

Comment: $\Gamma 's$ are just sets.

Comment: If the $\,\Gamma'\,$s are just sets then it suffices to show $\,\Gamma_1\subset \Gamma_2\,$

Comment: Technically the permutation group $G_1$ cannot be a subgroup of the permutation group $G_2$ unless $\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2$. If $\Gamma_1\subseteq\Gamma_2$ then $G_1$ can be isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_2$.